# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/telegram/telegrambots/meta/exceptions/TelegramApiException

Tags: java, maven, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy my first java application using Maven. In this case, this is just a simply telegram bot, but I get this error when trying to run it locally. After a little investigation, I found that **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError** is an error that occurs when a jar file is not able to access a specific class in runtime, and in order to solve this, is necessary to add that class on *classpath*.
I understand that when working on Maven, there is a simple way to add classes on the classpath, and it's by adding the right dependency on the pom.xml file.
So this is what i've added:

```
     <dependencies>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
             <artifactId>telegrambots-abilities</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.1.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
             <artifactId>telegrambots</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.1</version>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
             <groupId>org.telegram</groupId>
             <artifactId>telegrambots-meta</artifactId>
             <version>5.0.1.1</version>
         </dependency>
     </dependencies>
```

And I think it was successfully added on the classpath because this is what I get when I read the MANIFEST.MF file on my jar file:

```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Created-By: Apache Maven 3.6.3
   Built-By: agujared
   Build-Jdk: 15.0.1
   Class-Path: telegrambots-abilities-5.0.1.1.jar commons-lang3-3.11.jar ma
    pdb-3.0.8.jar kotlin-stdlib-1.2.71.jar kotlin-stdlib-common-1.2.71.jar
    annotations-13.0.jar eclipse-collections-api-11.0.0.M1.jar eclipse-coll
    ections-11.0.0.M1.jar eclipse-collections-forkjoin-11.0.0.M1.jar lz4-1.
    3.0.jar elsa-3.0.0-M5.jar slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar telegrambots-5.0.1.jar j
   ackson-annotations-2.11.3.jar jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.11.3.jar ja
   ckson-jaxrs-base-2.11.3.jar jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.11.3.jar
   jackson-core-2.11.3.jar jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar jakarta.activati
   on-api-1.2.1.jar jackson-databind-2.11.3.jar jersey-hk2-2.32.jar jersey
   -common-2.32.jar osgi-resource-locator-1.0.3.jar jakarta.activation-1.2
   .2.jar hk2-locator-2.6.1.jar aopalliance-repackaged-2.6.1.jar hk2-api-2
   .6.1.jar hk2-utils-2.6.1.jar javassist-3.25.0-GA.jar jersey-media-json-
   jackson-2.32.jar jersey-entity-filtering-2.32.jar jersey-container-griz
   zly2-http-2.32.jar jakarta.inject-2.6.1.jar grizzly-http-server-2.4.4.j
   ar grizzly-http-2.4.4.jar grizzly-framework-2.4.4.jar jakarta.ws.rs-api
   -2.1.6.jar jersey-server-2.32.jar jersey-client-2.32.jar jersey-media-j
   axb-2.32.jar jakarta.annotation-api-1.3.5.jar jakarta.validation-api-2.
   0.2.jar json-20180813.jar httpclient-4.5.13.jar httpcore-4.4.13.jar com
   mons-logging-1.2.jar commons-codec-1.11.jar httpmime-4.5.13.jar commons
   -io-2.8.0.jar telegrambots-meta-5.0.1.1.jar guava-30.0-jre.jar failurea
   ccess-1.0.1.jar listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-gu
   ava.jar jsr305-3.0.2.jar checker-qual-3.5.0.jar error_prone_annotations
   -2.3.4.jar j2objc-annotations-1.3.jar
  Main-Class: domain.Main
```

As you can see, *telegrambots-meta-5.0.1.1.jar* is part of the classpath attribute.
How can I solve this?

By the way, I'm using Heroku Cloud to deploy this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want and need to create a **runnable/ executable JAR file** (with external dependencies).

This requires your build process to be enhanced by this step, regardless of where it is executed *Heroku*, *Jenkins*, *Bamboo* or on your local - this is a maven setting and will affect each of them.

Also on your local you can run the build of your project by executing `mvn clean package` in your IDE and afterwards to run the created JAR from the `target` folder with: `java -jar ${yourJarName}`. It'll likely fail for the same reason.

This is, because ***Maven*** dependencies are added with a so called scope. These are for example:

- **`compile`**
- `provided`
- `runtime`
- `test`

Whereby `compile` is the default one and being implicitly applied in case you don't specify it - like in your case. (You can read more about the scopes [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html))

This means ***Maven*** will add your dependency to your IDE at **compile time**, but it will be missing at the **runtime**, when your trying to execute it.

The solution is to create a **runnable/ executable JAR file** (also called *fat JAR *) containing all the needed dependencies.

You can do it directly within ***Maven*** with the help of the **maven-assembly-plugin** like so:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you need to build your JAR like:

```
mvn clean compile assembly:single
```

**Note:** *The compile goal must be added before assembly:single or otherwise the code on your own project is not included.*

---

To ease the handling of the process this goal commonly is tied to a ***Maven*** build phase to execute automatically. This ensures the JAR is built when executing `mvn clean package`, `mvn clean install` or performing a deployment/ release:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
                    <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Like this you can simply build your project with the `mvn clean package` command (probably the most common one) and it'll include the creation of the **runnable/ executable JAR file**. This will include all your needed dependencies and should resolve your *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError* issue.

---

**Just a short additional note**

Creating **runnable/ executable JAR file** respectively **fat JAR** is not the only solution and maybe in some contexts unwanted. Since fat JAR files include all their needed dependencies, they are fairly big with all the related drawbacks (requires more bandwith to transmit, download size increases, same dependencies might be carried in multiple different JARs, ...).

For this reasons the fat JAR creation is avoided in **Web Application Development with Java EE**. Dependencies are only added at *compile time*, since it is known that a **Servlet Container** or **Application Container** like *Tomcat* or *Wildfly* will provide these at *runtime* to avoid the *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError*. Therefore the different applications (JARs or in this context called WARs) don't need to provide the dependencies themself.

In your case it might also be the solution that you'll still build the thin JAR, but will provide the needed dependencies at runtime (e.g. separately downloading it and then specifying in the classpath before the execution).

Comment: Thank you very much! I just added those plugins and built using the maven commands. Worked fine. Just like I said, this was the first time for me deploying an app and using maven, so i think i will invest my time learning a little more about how it works. :)

Comment: Nice, I'm glad the answer helped you! Yes the build process as well as the operation of an application can be quite complex. Maven is doing a great job in unifying and simplifying it, but therefore it also requires some practice on its own - like others tend say to "get behind its *magic*". I'm sure you'll be able to do so, just like you say you 'just' need to spend some time and do some research - all information is out there :) All the best for this and thank you for officially accepting my answer! BR